# Swift and SwiftUI binding from TextField string to model's published, optional Integer property

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, swiftui, textfield

I'm new to Swift and SwiftUI and have a model with a @Published intValue optional and a view with a TextField where its text/string property is 2-way bound to intValue of the model. Need to make sure valid text entry as a string is converted to a valid integer for the model. What is the recommended approach to handle this in SwiftUI? Code is similar to below...

```
//Model
class AppModel:ObservedObject {
 @Published
 var intValue: Int? = 5
}

//View
@ObservedObject
 var appModel = AppModel.shared

TextField("", text: $appModel.intValue)
                    .keyboardType(.numberPad)
```

Updated sample code...

```
///////////
import SwiftUI

class Model: ObservableObject {
    static var shared: Model = Model()

    @Published
    var number: Int = 0

    init(){}

}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TextFieldFormatter()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}


struct TextFieldFormatter: View {
    @ObservedObject
    var model: Model = Model.shared

    @State private var number: Int = 0


    let formatter: NumberFormatter = {
        let numFormatter = NumberFormatter()
        numFormatter.numberStyle = .none
        return numFormatter
    }()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("State").onTapGesture {
                self.endEditing()
            }
            TextField("int", value: $number, formatter: formatter).keyboardType(.numberPad)
            Text("Echo: \(number)")
            Text("Observable")
            TextField("int", value: $model.number, formatter: formatter).keyboardType(.numberPad)
            Text("Echo: \(model.number)")
        }
    }
}

struct TextFieldFormatter_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TextFieldFormatter()
    }
}

extension View {
    func endEditing() {
        UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to:nil, from:nil, for:nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SwiftUI's TextField has several Constructors. One of them takes a Formatter parameter.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/textfield

```
import SwiftUI

struct TextFieldFormatter: View {
    @ObservedObject var model: Model = Model.shared

    let formatter: NumberFormatter = {
        let numFormatter = NumberFormatter()
        numFormatter.numberStyle = .none
        return numFormatter
    }()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("State").onTapGesture {
                self.endEditing()
            }
            TextField("int", value: $model.number, formatter: formatter).keyboardType(.numberPad)
            Text("Echo: \(model.number)")
            Text("Observable")
            TextField("int", value: $model.number, formatter: formatter).keyboardType(.numberPad)
            Text("Echo: \(model.number)")
        }
    }
}

struct TextFieldFormatter_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TextFieldFormatter()
    }
}
```

Also, if you are trying to disable the screen with the onTapGesture you might consider.

adding:

```
   @State var disabled: Bool = false
```

and changing:

```
       Form {
            Text("Disable").onTapGesture {
                //self.endEditing()
                self.disabled = true
            }
            TextField("int", value: $model.number, formatter: formatter).keyboardType(.numberPad)
            Text("Echo: \(model.number)")
            Text("Observable")
            TextField("int", value: $model.number, formatter: formatter).keyboardType(.numberPad)
            Text("Echo: \(model.number)")
        }.disabled($disabled.wrappedValue)
```

Giving feedback while the user is typing can be done a few different ways but a custom `UITextView` in a `UIViewRepresentable` class seems to be the most common.

Comment: I updated the sample code with your code and added in @Observable object. The bound variable using state nor the model using observedobject still appears not update when a change is made to the textfield.

Comment: I made a minor change. Removing the State var and referencing the model.number it all works after you press Return

Comment: But for example, the new `TextEditor` only provide the `Binding<String>` constructor. Which makes thing cumbersome.

Answer (score 12):

You can create a custom `Binding` to pass in to the `TextField`.

This is how to construct a `Binding<String>` (what the `TextField` needs):

```swift
var string = ""

let myBinding = Binding(get: { string }) {
    string = $0
}
```

The first argument of the `Binding` constructor is the getter. This closure should return a value of the desired type.

The second argument is a setter. It is a closure that takes in the new value, and does something with it (usually set another value).

So, if you want to create a `Binding<String>` to pass in to the `TextField` that gets/sets `appModel.intValue`, you can create a `Binding<String>` and pass it into the `TextField` like this:

```swift
TextField("", text: .init(
    get: { self.appModel.intValue.map(String.init) ?? "" },
    set: { self.appModel.intValue = Int($0) }
))
.keyboardType(.numberPad)
```

Comment: Got an error Generic parameter T could not be inferred on map function. Made a few changes and came up with something that compiles, and updates, but editing the text field is problematic with this approach. Can append a digit but can't backspace delete digits. Here's the code I used.

TextField("int", text: myBinding)

let myBinding = Binding(
            get: { String(self.appModel.intValue)},
            set: { self.appModel.intValue = (Int($0) ?? 5)})

Comment: Didn't you want appModel.intValue to be an optional?