# How to connect two ViewModels inside MVVM, iOS, UIKit

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, uikit, viewmodel

I am writing weather app which contains two controllers and two view models WeatherViewModel and SearchViewModel

class WeatherViewModel {

```
var searchViewModel: SearchViewModel
var bindableWeather = Bindable<OverallWeatherModel>()


init(searchViewModel: SearchViewModel){
    self.searchViewModel = searchViewModel
    searchViewModel.bindableSearchWeather.bind { [weak self] weather in
        self?.bindableWeather.value = weather
    }
}
```

}

class SearchViewModel {

```
var bindableSearchWeather = Bindable<OverallWeatherModel>()
var searchCity: String? {didSet {fetchCityData(city: searchCity ?? "")}}

fileprivate var overallWeatherModel =  OverallWeatherModel()

fileprivate func fetchCityData(city: String) {
    Service.shared.fetchCityData(city: city) {[weak self] cityGroup in
        guard let city = cityGroup.first else {return}
        self?.overallWeatherModel.city = city.name
        self?.overallWeatherModel.country = city.country
        self?.fetchWeatherData(lat: city.lat, long: city.lon)
    }
}

fileprivate func fetchWeatherData(lat: Double, long: Double) {
    Service.shared.fetchTempData(lat: lat, long: long) {[weak self] weatherGroup in
        self?.overallWeatherModel.date = DateFormat.shared.currentDate()
        self?.overallWeatherModel.temp = Int(weatherGroup.main.temp - 273)
        let weatherIcon = "http://openweathermap.org/img/w/\(weatherGroup.weather?.first?.icon ?? "").png"
        self?.overallWeatherModel.weatherIconUrl = URL(string: weatherIcon)
        self?.overallWeatherModel.windStatus = Int(weatherGroup.wind.speed)
        self?.overallWeatherModel.humidity = weatherGroup.main.humidity
        self?.overallWeatherModel.visibility = weatherGroup.visibility
        self?.overallWeatherModel.airPressure = weatherGroup.main.pressure
        self?.fetchNextWeekData(lat: lat, long: long)
    }
}
fileprivate func fetchNextWeekData(lat: Double, long: Double) {
    Service.shared.fetchTempDataForWeek(lat: lat, long: long) { [weak self] nextweek in
        self?.overallWeatherModel.temp1 = Int(nextweek.list[0].main.temp - 273)
        self?.overallWeatherModel.temp2 = Int(nextweek.list[1].main.temp - 273)
        self?.overallWeatherModel.temp3 = Int(nextweek.list[2].main.temp - 273)
        self?.overallWeatherModel.temp4 = Int(nextweek.list[3].main.temp - 273)
        self?.overallWeatherModel.temp5 = Int(nextweek.list[4].main.temp - 273)
        let weatherIcon1 = "http://openweathermap.org/img/w/\(nextweek.list[0].weather.first?.icon ?? "").png"
        let weatherIcon2 = "http://openweathermap.org/img/w/\(nextweek.list[1].weather.first?.icon ?? "").png"
        let weatherIcon3 = "http://openweathermap.org/img/w/\(nextweek.list[2].weather.first?.icon ?? "").png"
        let weatherIcon4 = "http://openweathermap.org/img/w/\(nextweek.list[3].weather.first?.icon ?? "").png"
        let weatherIcon5 = "http://openweathermap.org/img/w/\(nextweek.list[4].weather.first?.icon ?? "").png"
        self?.overallWeatherModel.icon1 = URL(string: weatherIcon1)
        self?.overallWeatherModel.icon2 = URL(string: weatherIcon2)
        self?.overallWeatherModel.icon3 = URL(string: weatherIcon3)
        self?.overallWeatherModel.icon4 = URL(string: weatherIcon4)
        self?.overallWeatherModel.icon5 = URL(string: weatherIcon5)
        self?.overallWeatherModel.date1 = DateFormat.shared.nextDate(day: 1)
        self?.overallWeatherModel.date2 = DateFormat.shared.nextDate(day: 2)
        self?.overallWeatherModel.date3 = DateFormat.shared.nextDate(day: 3)
        self?.overallWeatherModel.date4 = DateFormat.shared.nextDate(day: 4)
        self?.overallWeatherModel.date5 = DateFormat.shared.nextDate(day: 5)
        self?.bindableSearchWeather.value = self?.overallWeatherModel
    }
}
```

}

SearchViewModel is creating an API call and getting data, then I am sending this data to the WeatherVewModel, which is in charge of changing view on its controller. For passing data I am using Observable/Bindable and also embedding SearchViewModel inside of WeatherVewModel so it can send data to it. My question is am I doing this correctly or not? Have a feeling that embedding one viewmodel inside of another isn't right.

Comment: Is SearchViewModel used by a controller as well? If yes then I would move all search functionality into a new type and use this type from both view models. If no then it’s not a view model.

Comment: SwiftUI to UIKit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60085865/swift-and-swiftui-binding-from-textfield-string-to-models-published-optional-i/60086061#60086061

Comment: UIKit to SwiftUI https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70435695/call-uikit-function-from-swiftui/70437340#70437340

Comment: View models shouldn’t know about each other.

Comment: How are you creating your view models and propagating them? Are you using a coordinator? I'd be curious to see how you are doing that. That said, I wouldn't pass a view model to another. I'd pass a protocol that your embedded view model conforms to.

Answer (score 0):

each View should have its own view model,

SearchViewController should have(know about) -> SearchViewModel and
WeatherViewController should have(know about) -> WeatherViewModel

when you fetch data from the SearchViewModel if you should present or show another view for example push:

```
let weatherViewModel = WeatherViewModel(weatherParamsYouFetchInSearchViewModel: ...x..)
let vc = WeatherViewController(viewModel: weatherViewModel)
push(vc, animated: true)
```

your WeatherViewController should have this initialization

```
class WeatherViewController: UIViewController {
    let viewModel: WeatherViewModel!
    
    init(viewModel: WeatherViewModel) {
        self.viewModel = viewModel
        super.init(nibName: WeatherViewModel.nameOfClass, bundle: nil)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```